# SQLAlchemy bug (?) triggers "(ProgrammingError) table name [...] specified more than once"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy (0.8.7 and also 0.9.7) is generating bad SQL for Postgresql 9.3, and I suspect it is a bug, but I am not confident enough yet to dismiss user error.

Here is a snippet of my test-case code.

```
    print "--- Snip Start ---"
    print "target_table", self.target_table
    print "update_where_binding", update_where_binding
    print "update_values_binding", update_values_binding
    table_update = (
        self.target_table.update(
            whereclause=update_where_binding, values=update_values_binding)
    )

    print "Query", table_update

    print "Data", updates
    print "Starting query"
    self.session.execute(
            table_update, updates)
    print "Completed query"
    print "--- Snip End ---"
```

Here is the result.

```
--- Snip Start ---
target_table Dummy
update_where_binding "Dummy".pa_name = :b_pa_name
update_values_binding {'pa_name_hash': BindParameter('pa_name_hash', None, type_=NullType())}
Query UPDATE "Dummy" SET pa_name_hash=%(pa_name_hash)s FROM "Dummy" WHERE "Dummy".pa_name = %(b_pa_name)s
```

(I'll just interject here to say - look! The bug has already happened. The `FROM "Dummy"` part is extraneous, because the table name already appears in as the second word of the query. But continuing for now...)

```
Data [{'b_pa_name': '5', 'pa_name_hash': 'x'}, {'b_pa_name': '6', 'pa_name_hash': 'y'}]
Starting query

Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) table name "Dummy" specified more than once
 'UPDATE "Dummy" SET pa_name_hash=%(pa_name_hash)s FROM "Dummy" WHERE "Dummy".pa_name = %(b_pa_name)s' ({'b_pa_name': '5', 'pa_name_hash': 'x'}, {'b_pa_name': '6', 'pa_name_hash': 'y'})
```

Does this look like a bug in SQLAlchemy to you, or is there an alternative explanation?